# Querying elasticsearch in Kibana using Json

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have set up my Elk stack and everything seems to be working perfectly in terms of indexing and filtering data that i require.

My log file contains the following :

```
123          20126254      6718  Chicken
1234         20326254      6718  Bread
123          20126254      6718  Chicken
123          20126254      6718  Chicken
12345        20426254      6718  Rice
123456       20526254      6718  apples
123          20126254      6718  Chicken
```

When i filter the results with grok i get the following output for each line in my log file:

```
OrderNumber : 123
ProductId: 20126254 
ProductType:  6718
ProductName: Chicken
```

I need some advice on how to go about querying this data in elastic search in order to get specific results.

This is what i would like to do:

***Select all OrderNumbers that contain the same productId***

Please  advise me  on how i should go about doing this?

Should i use json?

Thanks.

Comment: Your subject line says Kibana, where the query would be "ProductId:20126254" to query for a single id.

Comment: Yes that works for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you find this question only because you want to use JSON to query Kibana:

Click on "Add a filter" and then "Edit Query DSL", you'll get a textarea field where you can paste a JSON query.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query data in Elasticsearch using below query

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/<indexName>/<typename>/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "ProductId" : "20126254" }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Roopendra, i am trying to execute this in Power Shell but it isn't working. Im Running Elk in Windows environment.