# Is there a way to convert a json query to a human-usable Kibana link?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I have a Go program to summarize some data from an Elasticsearch database, employing the go-elasticsearch client.  The query string is a bit more complicated than this, but this is the gist:

```
query := `{"stored_fields": ["_source"], "query": {"bool": {"must":[{"match": {"Area.Dealer": "` +
    myData.DealerName + `"}}, {"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "` +
    startTimeString + `", "lte": "` + endTimeString + `"}}}]}}, "size": 2000}`
```

Because the output of my Go program is a summary, the report leaves out a lot of data.  So, I was wondering if there is a way that I can convert this JSON query easily to a URL which will point to a Kibana server to report the same data, but give the full details?

Comment: how should that link look like in this case?

Comment: I am not sure.  That's one of the things that I'm asking.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way to do this.  So, what I did was to grab my JSON that I have in my code, then paste it as a query, as described here:

[Querying elasticsearch in Kibana using Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286222/querying-elasticsearch-in-kibana-using-json/66257603#66257603)

Then, I essentially built the URL to match the one that I just generated from the link above.  Ugly, but functional.